# How to send vectors to Redis cache for vector similarity?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Im trying to implement vector search similarity in c#. I have to use the HSET command to send vectors to my index in Redis. The hset command is something like: HSET item:3 "\x00\x00\x00\x00". When I test this, I find out that the string I add which is "\x00\x00\x00\x00" gets added as ""\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00". **Redis does not remove the extra backslash and thus my searching fails later on.**

```
   public static async Task CreateIndexAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await mux.GetDatabase().ExecuteAsync("FT.CREATE", "embeddings", "ON", "HASH", "PREFIX", "1", "item:", "SCHEMA", "vector", "VECTOR", "FLAT", "6", "TYPE", "FLOAT32", "DIM", "2", "DISTANCE_METRIC", "COSINE");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //swallow exception if index exists
        }
    }`

    public static async Task AddAsync(string docId, string prefix, float[] vector)
    {
        string hex = toHexString(vector);
         mux.GetDatabase().Execute("Hset", $"{prefix}{docId}", "vector", hex);
    }`
```

I dont know how to solve this issue, it seems that Redis does not have good c# support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are more than welcome to use NRedisStack, A .NET client (builds on StackExchange.Redis) and supports Redis Stack commands.
NRedisStack has support for vector search similarity commands.

Your code will look like that with NRedisStack:

```
public static async Task CreateIndexAsync()
{
    try
    {
         await ft.CreateAsync("embeddings",
         new FTCreateParams()
         .On(IndexDataType.Hash)
         .Prefix("item:"),
         new Schema()
         .AddVectorField("vector",
         VectorField.VectorAlgo.FLAT,
         new Dictionary<string, object>()
         {
             ["TYPE"] = "FLOAT32",
             ["DIM"] = "2",
             ["DISTANCE_METRIC"] = "COSINE"
         }));
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           //swallow exception if index exists
       }
   }

public static async Task AddAsync(string docId, string prefix, float[] vector)
{
    db.HashSet($"{prefix}{docId}", "vector", toHexString(vector));
}
```

I tried to reproduce the problem you described, while using NRedisStack, and this line worked fine:

```
var res = db.HashSet("item", "vector", "\x00\x00\x00\x00");
```

this is the monitor output:

```
~"FT.CREATE" "embeddings" "PREFIX" "1" "item:" "SCHEMA" "vector" "VECTOR" "FLAT" "6" "TYPE" "FLOAT32" "DIM" "2" "DISTANCE_METRIC" "COSINE"
~"HSET" "item:3" "vector" "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

Links:
[NRedisStack - link to github](https://github.com/redis/NRedisStack) |
[NRedisStack - link to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NRedisStack)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear from the answer of Shachar Pashchur. You don't have to translate it to an escaped hexadecimal sequence.

You can just pass a flattened byte array of `float` or `double` values into the hashset.

```
public static async Task CreateIndexAsync()
{
    try
    {
         await ft.CreateAsync("embeddings",
         new FTCreateParams()
         .On(IndexDataType.Hash)
         .Prefix("item:"),
         new Schema()
         .AddVectorField("vector",
         VectorField.VectorAlgo.FLAT,
         new Dictionary<string, object>()
         {
             ["TYPE"] = "FLOAT32",
             ["DIM"] = "2",
             ["DISTANCE_METRIC"] = "COSINE"
         }));
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           //swallow exception if index exists
       }
   }

public static async Task AddAsync(string docId, string prefix, float[] vector)
{
    db.HashSet($"{prefix}{docId}", "vector", vector.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray());
}
```

If you are going to pass in an array of `double` values, remember to change the `VectorField` `TYPE` to `FLOAT64`